# How to disable strapi::security middleware?

Tags: strapi

I am using my own user management system. I added my own custom middleware to verify my users. I am able to verify my user through custom middleware, but strapi's default middleware is blocking to access API. Is there any way to disable it?

I am excepting to be able to access API after being verified by custom middleware.

Version:
strapi = v4
node = v16